# Create a mesh (.ply file) from o3d.geometry.lineset()

Tags: python, open3d

I am new to open3d, and I have a code that gets me a [lineset](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.LineSet.html) class and then visualise it.
I want to save that lineset to a 3d mesh (.ply file), does anyone knows how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the docs. [write_line_set()](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.io.write_line_set.html#open3d.io.write_line_set).

From the Docs:

```
open3d.io.write_line_set(filename, line_set, write_ascii=False, compressed=False, print_progress=False)
```

So straight forward:

```
import open3d as o3d

line_set = # your line set

succeeded = o3d.io.write_line_set("line_set.ply", line_set, print_progress=True)

if succeeded:
    print('Successfully saved')
else:
    print('Error occurred while saving the line set')
```